# fullcalendar how to change the actual value of start/end from ISO8601 date string to other format

Tags: fullcalendar

fullcalendar 6.x.

my code for events as json feed looks like:

```
    calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
                height: "auto",
                headerToolbar: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
                },
                events: {
                    url: "/myurl",  
                    extraParams: function() { // a function that returns an object
                        return {
                            createId: $("#createId").val()
                        };
                    }

                }
```

the actual value of `start`/`end` looks like `2023-04-30T00:00:00+08:00`.

how can I change it to other format, e.g. `2023-04-30 00:00:00`?

Comment: Use the [events as a function](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function) pattern. Then you can write your own AJAX code, and thus have full control over the request being sent to the server, and its contents.

Comment: Got it. Thanks! That is there is no possible when using events as json feed.